# How can I solve this Android Studio Firebase problem?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data from Firebase to bilgiler variable. But I get error all the time. How can I solve this?

```
Map<String, String> bilgiler = new HashMap<>();

db.collection("tarihBilgi")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {
                                //Log.d("TAG", document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                                bilgiler.put("asdf", document.getData().toString());
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.w("TAG", "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
        Log.i("asdfads",(bilgiler.get("asdf")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. Right now your `Log.i("asdfads",(bilgiler.get("asdf")));` is run before `bilgiler.put("asdf", document.getData().toString())` runs, which explains why you don't see the value from the database.

Any code that needs data from the database, needs to be inside the `onComplete` method, or be called from there. So:

```
db.collection("tarihBilgi")
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {
                    bilgiler.put("asdf", document.getData().toString());
                    Log.i("asdfads",(bilgiler.get("asdf")));
                }
            } else {
                Log.w("TAG", "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

Also see:

- [How to check a certain data already exists in firestore or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000169/how-to-check-a-certain-data-already-exists-in-firestore-or-not/51002413#51002413)
- [User login in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53244038/user-login-in-firebase/53244113#53244113)
- [How to return a DocumentSnapShot as a result of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/how-to-return-a-documentsnapshot-as-a-result-of-a-method/48500679#48500679)
- [Wait until Firestore data is retrieved to launch an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650224/wait-until-firestore-data-is-retrieved-to-launch-an-activity/50680352#50680352)
- [Problems with Firestore connections executing threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52057313/problems-with-firestore-connections-executing-threads/52059411#52059411)